# Multi-Website, Multi-Prices - A common scenario made complicated

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, multicurrency

My first question here. I am developing a Magento 2 Website under *1* Domain. We have 7 areas in the world where we have 7 different prices.

Now I learned, Magento 2 (and even 1) is not switching prices on Store Scope but on Website Scope. How can I add a Switcher? Users should be able to switch to different shops.

It is a basic Shop by Country scenario but I am totally lost right now.
Please...please help.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the options you have,

1. Create different websites, and import the products with the different prices. Now you can switch between the shops using the store view names like,

   ```
   www.yourdomain.com/shop1/
   www.yourdomain.com/shop2/
   ```

   shop1 and shop2 are the individual stores view names of the different websites.

   From admin end you can enable the option to append the store_view name with your url.
2. Otherwise, like `Tier Price` you can create your own logic and provide different prices. While switching the shop, set the appropriate price in the `setFianlPrice` element.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that Magento default just allows setting prices for the whole website. You want to set up different prices for store views, right? So that your customers in each store view will buy products at various prices. 
I think you need to consider an extension to solve this issue. For example

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-store-view-pricing.html

I see that this extension allows setting up different prices/ special prices of product per store view. You can read more about it to see whether it meets your requirements